# sge All queues dropped because of overload or full

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I'm going to run a million batch jobs with " sge ".

Approximately 10,000 jobs are well executed, but after an hour of execution, they stop running.

After about an hour's run, the process slows down and eventually stops.

Checking the error message does not confirm any errors.

i can check the message below only.

"All queues dropped because of overload or full"

How do I set up the layout to run normally?

there is one master server and four clients and files share using nfs
and every system run on docker and docker-swirm

do qstat when job execution speed was slow down

```
$qstat -j
queue instance "peteris.q@sge00" dropped because it is full
queue instance "peteris.q@sge02" dropped because it is full
queue instance "peteris.q@sge03" dropped because it is full
queue instance "peteris.q@sge01" dropped because it is full
All queues dropped because of overload or full
```

detail messages

```
$qstat -j 1595799
=============================================================
job_number:                 1595799
exec_file:                  job_scripts/1595799
submission_time:            Sun May 27 08:08:10 2018
owner:                      root
uid:                        0
group:                      root
gid:                        0
sge_o_home:                 /root
sge_o_path:                         /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
sge_o_workdir:              /data/23andMe
sge_o_host:                 sge
account:                    sge
cwd:                        /data/23andMe
mail_list:                  root@sge
notify:                     FALSE
job_name:                   python3
jobshare:                   0
env_list:
job_args:                   lineage.py,makeShell/1009_user3130_user3600.list
script_file:                python3
usage    1:                 cpu=00:00:02, mem=0.59503 GBs, io=0.03963,     vmem=493.180M, maxvmem=493.180M
scheduling info:            queue instance "peteris.q@sge00" dropped because     it is full
                        queue instance "peteris.q@sge02" dropped because it is full
                        queue instance "peteris.q@sge03" dropped because it is full
                        queue instance "peteris.q@sge01" dropped because it is full
                        All queues dropped because of overload or full
```

sge config

```
algorithm default
schedule_interval 0:0:10
maxujobs 0
queue_sort_method load
job_load_adjustments np_load_avg=100.0
load_adjustment_decay_time 0:7:30
load_formula np_load_avg
schedd_job_info true
flush_submit_sec 2
flush_finish_sec 2
params none
reprioritize_interval 0:0:0
halftime 168
usage_weight_list cpu=1.000000,mem=0.000000,io=0.000000
compensation_factor 5.000000
weight_user 0.250000
weight_project 0.250000
weight_department 0.250000
weight_job 0.250000
weight_tickets_functional 0
weight_tickets_share 0
share_override_tickets TRUE
share_functional_shares TRUE
max_functional_jobs_to_schedule 200
report_pjob_tickets TRUE
max_pending_tasks_per_job 50
halflife_decay_list none
policy_hierarchy OFS
weight_ticket 0.500000
weight_waiting_time 0.278000
weight_deadline 3600000.000000
weight_urgency 0.500000
weight_priority 0.000000
max_reservation 0
default_duration INFINITY
```

sge queue config

```
qname                 peteris.q
hostlist              @allhosts
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       NONE
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:00:05
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:00:05
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               make
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 20
tmpdir                /tmp
shell                 /bin/bash
prolog                NONE
epilog                NONE
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant
starter_method        NONE
suspend_method        NONE
resume_method         NONE
terminate_method      NONE
notify                00:00:01
owner_list            NONE
user_lists            NONE
xuser_lists           NONE
subordinate_list      NONE
complex_values        NONE
projects              NONE
xprojects             NONE
calendar              NONE
initial_state         default
s_rt                  INFINITY
h_rt                  INFINITY
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_stack               INFINITY
h_stack               INFINITY
s_core                INFINITY
h_core                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                INFINITY
```

Comment: To clarify, please state whether you are executing `qsub` command 1M times, or are you using job array?

Comment: Execute Qsub at master server and Qstat at master server, and don`t use job array

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have hit a practical limit on the number of active jobs that the queue can handle at any given time. I cannot confirm where the maximum is defined by SGE, but seems likely it is:

> max_jobs
>
> The number of  active  (not  finished)  jobs  simultaneously
>        allowed  in Sun Grid Engine is controlled by this parameter.
>        A value greater than 0 defines the limit. The default  value
>        0  means "unlimited". If the max_jobs limit is exceeded by a
>        job submission then the submission command exits  with  exit
>        status 25 and an appropriate error message.
>        Changing max_jobs will take immediate effect. 
>        This value is a global configuration parameter only. It can-
>        not  be  overwritten  by the execution host local configura-
>        tion.

From: http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_conf.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG

If this is correct then value is unlimited; however, SGE will likely not perform well trying to manage ~1 million active jobs, hence the issue you are likely having.  I would recommend you use **job arrays**, as this is the purpose of this type of job ie, to manage and run **many near identical tasks**.

There are many resources online for job arrays in SGE, such as this one:

http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto

http://talby.rcs.manchester.ac.uk/~ri/_linux_and_hpc_lib/sge_array.html

https://wiki.duke.edu/display/SCSC/SGE+Array+Jobs

I am happy to assist further if you edit your question with specific requirements for each task. For example, does each of the ~ 1 millions tasks require one or more parameters as input?

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. But i did it already set maxjobs to 0

Comment: So setting `maxjobs` to `0` solved the issue? Or, you already set `maxjobs` to `0`  and issue persists?

Comment: I suspect issue is SGE cannot control that number of jobs given the resources of the submit node. For workload involving thousands of tasks it is recommended to use task arrays.